# Count of rows between two specific rows with same class using jquery

Tags: jquery, html

I have table structure like:

```
<table>
  <tr class="1">
    <td>Parent 1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Parent 2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Parent 3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Parent 4</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="1">
    <td>Parent 5</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Parent 6</td>
  </tr>

  ...
  ...
</table>
```

I have tr with same class.
I want count of tr between tr with class "1" using jquery.

like here it should be 3

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [`.nextUntil()`](http://api.jquery.com/nextuntil/)

```
$(".1").first().nextUntil(".1").length
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/satpalsingh/DWeZe/)

Comment: Damn, 8 seconds faster. Should I delete mine?

Comment: @ShaunakD, NO you have not copied it so fine. Clearly you reached answer on your own.

Comment: it is giving correct result for first i.e. 3 but second time it should be 1...it is showing 3 everytime

Comment: @KerenCaelen, Currently I have use `.first()` thus its giving 3 every time. Here updated fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/satpalsingh/hMzHZ/

Comment: if I remove .first(), it is giving result as 4

Comment: I want to set this value to a variable in a loop.. first time value should be 3 ..next time 1...

Comment: @KerenCaelen, http://jsfiddle.net/satpalsingh/Q97R2/ In fiddle you have `arr` or http://jsfiddle.net/satpalsingh/Q97R2/1/

Comment: @Satpal :thnx for the help

Answer (score 4):

Use **[`.nextUntil()`](http://api.jquery.com/nextuntil/)**

```
$('.1:first').nextUntil('.1').length
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/TdvLL/)**